# Adding .mouseleave to jplayer <script> to pause music when leaving <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

I am building a webpage which has two music players for sampling preferences. I am having trouble with making the music stop for both music player as the cursor leaves the division both players are in. (I have already made the first music player pause the second music player when played and vice versa.)

I used:

```
play: function() { //** added script from demo to pause other players **// 
              $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers"); 
          },
```

It is meant to prevent multiple players from playing at the same time using .jplayer("pauseOthers")

Should I edit the (head)[tag] javascript for jplayer to listen for .mouseleave so to pause both music players? (I have the normal layout for jplayer in HTML)

EDIT:

Head: javascript

```
 25 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 26 //<![CDATA[ 
 27 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 28  
 29     $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({ 
 30         ready: function () { 
 31             $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { 
 32                 title: "sample 1", 
 33                 mp3: "Music/sample1.mp3" 
 34             }); 
 35         }, 
 36         play: function() { //** added script from demo **// 
 37             $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers"); 
 38         },
             // add .mouseleave code
            pause: function() {
                $("#containerjplayer").mouseleave("pauseOthers");
            },


 39         swfPath: "swf/", 
 40         supplied: "mp3", 
 41         globalVolume: true, 
 42         smoothPlayBar: true, 
 43         keyEnabled: true 
 44     }); 
 45  
 46     $("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer({ 
 47         ready: function () { 
 48             $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { 
 49                 title: "Sample 2", 
 50                 mp3: "http://jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3" 
 51                 }); 
 52         }, 
 53         play: function() { // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together. 
 54             $(this).jplayer("pauseOthers"); 
 55         }, 

            pause: function() {
                $("#containerjplayer").mouseleave("pauseOthers");
            },

 56         swfPath: "swf/", 
 57         supplied: "mp3", 
 58         cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_2", 
 59         globalVolume: true, 
 60         smoothPlayBar: true, 
 61         keyEnabled: true 
 62     }); 
 63  
 64 }); 
 65 //]]> 
 66 </script>
```

Adding to both:

```
// jquery_jplayer_1
pause: function() {
$("#containerjplayer").mouseleave("stop");
}
```

or

```
// jquery_jplayer_1
pause: function() {
$("#containerjplayer").mouseleave("pauseOthers");
}
```

I added "play: function" in the top script and it did as the demo displayed after looking at the DOM and instructions. Shouldn't adding "pause: function" with .mouseleave work?

[multiple instance jplayer](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-03/)

If not, is there a different way to do that?

(I have the normal layout for jplayer in HTML)

EDIT: added the HTML file

```
  1<!DOCTYPE html>
  2 <html><head>
  3   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  4   <title>Web testing</title>
  5   
  6   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--- Goes to js files     -->
  7   
  8   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  9   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
 10   
 11     
 12       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bluemonday.css"> <!-- Works: Goes     to CSS file and gets JPEG and gif -->
 13     
 14   
 15     
 16       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script> <!-- Jplay    er Jquery -->
 17     
 18   
 19   <style type="text/css">
 20 
 21   </style>
 22   
 23 <!--------------------                       Script for Playing music and stopping multi    ple music playback                 ------------>
 24 
 25 <script type="text/javascript">
 26 //<![CDATA[
 27 $(document).ready(function(){
 28 
 29     $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
 30         ready: function () {
 31             $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
 32                 title: "sample 1",
 33                 mp3: "Music/sample1.mp3"
 34             });
 35         },
 36         play: function() { // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together.
 37             $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
 38         },
            // add pause function and .mouseleave
            pause: function() {
                $("#containerjplayer").mouseleave("pauseOthers");
            },


 39         swfPath: "swf/",
 40         supplied: "mp3",
 41         globalVolume: true,
 42         smoothPlayBar: true,
 43         keyEnabled: true
 44     });
 45 
 46     $("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer({
 47         ready: function () {
 48             $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
 49                 title: "Sample 2",
 50                 mp3: "http://jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"
 51                 });
 52         },
 53         play: function() { // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together.
 54             $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
 55         },
            // add pause function and .mouseleave
            pause: function() {
                $("#containerjplayer").mouseleave("pauseOthers");
            },


 56         swfPath: "swf/",
 57         supplied: "mp3",
 58         cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_2",
 59         globalVolume: true,
 60         smoothPlayBar: true,
 61         keyEnabled: true
 62     });
 63 
 64 });
 65 //]]>
 66 </script>
 67 
 68 
 69 <!-----------------              END OF SCRIPT   -------------------->
 70 
 71 <style type="text/css"></style></head>
 72 <body>
 73 Which song do you like
 74 
 75 <div id="containerjplayer">
 76 
 77 
 78 <div id="blcoloredcontainer" href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause">
 79 <!---------------                     First Container                 ------------------    >
 80 
 81 
 82   <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"><img st    yle="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;" id="jp_poster_0"><audio title="Where Money     Flows Like Water" src="http://jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3" preload=    "metadata" id="jp_audio_0"></audio></div> <!-- Made an edit to music -->
 83 
 84 <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
 85     <div class="jp-type-single">
 86         <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
 87             <ul class="jp-controls">
 88 
 89                 <!-- comment out any of the following <li>s to remove these buttons -->
 90 
 91                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1" style="display:     none;">play</a></li>
 92                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1" style="display:     block;">pause</a></li>
 93                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
 94                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mut    e</a></li>
 95                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute"     style="display: none;">unmute</a></li>
 96                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max     volume">max volume</a></li>
 97             </ul>
 98 
 99             <!-- you can comment out any of the following <div>s too -->
100 
101             <div class="jp-progress">
102                 <div class="jp-seek-bar" style="width: 100%;">
103                     <div class="jp-play-bar" style="width: 2.81491%;"></div>
104                 </div>
105             </div>
106             <div class="jp-volume-bar">
107                 <div class="jp-volume-bar-value" style="width: 80%;"></div>
108             </div>
109             <div class="jp-current-time">00:16</div>
110             <div class="jp-duration">09:45</div>
111         </div>
112         <div class="jp-details">
113             <ul>
114                 <li><span class="jp-title">Sample 1</span></li>
115             </ul>
116         </div>
117         <div class="jp-no-solution" style="display: none;">
118             <span>Update Required</span>
119             To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent ve    rsion or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash p    lugin</a>.
120         </div>
121     </div>
122 </div>
123 
124 </div>
125 
126 <!--- ***blue color container script*** ------>
127 <script type="text/javascript">
128 $(document).ready(function(){
129     $("#blcoloredcontainer").mouseleave(function(event){
130         alert("Thanks");
131         });
132    });
133 </script>
134 
135 <!--- blue color container script ------>
136 <div id="recoloredcontainer">
137 
138 
139 <!-----------------                                Break to second container                                                ---------------->
140 
141   <div id="jquery_jplayer_2" class="jp-jplayer" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"><img st    yle="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;" id="jp_poster_0"><audio title="Battle" src    ="http://jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3" preload="metadata" id="jp_audi    o_0"></audio></div> <!-- Made an edit to music -->
142 
143 <div id="jp_container_2" class="jp-audio">
144     <div class="jp-type-single">
145         <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
146             <ul class="jp-controls">
147 
148                 <!---- comment out any of the following <li>s to remove these buttons --    >
149 
150                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1" style="display:     none;">play</a></li>
151                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1" style="display:     block;">pause</a></li>
152                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
153                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mut    e</a></li>
154                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute"     style="display: none;">unmute</a></li>
155                 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max     volume">max volume</a></li>
156             </ul>
157 
158             <!-- you can comment out any of the following <div>s too -->
159 
160             <div class="jp-progress">
161                 <div class="jp-seek-bar" style="width: 100%;">
162                     <div class="jp-play-bar" style="width: 2.81491%;"></div>
163                 </div>
164             </div>
165             <div class="jp-volume-bar">
166                 <div class="jp-volume-bar-value" style="width: 80%;"></div>
167             </div>
168             <div class="jp-current-time">00:16</div>
169             <div class="jp-duration">09:45</div>
170         </div>
171         <div class="jp-details">
172             <ul>
173                 <li><span class="jp-title">Sample 2</span></li>
174             </ul>
175         </div>
176         <div class="jp-no-solution" style="display: none;">
177             <span>Update Required</span>
178             To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent ve    rsion or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash p    lugin</a>.
179         </div>
180     </div>
181 </div>
182 
183 
184 </div>
185 
186 
187 </div>
188 </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So I found out the answer with more research and another stackoverflow question. What I needed to do to pause all music player with .mouseleave was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#blcoloredcontainer").mouseleave(function(event){
        $.jPlayer.pause();
        });
    $("#recoloredcontainer").mouseleave(function(event){
        $.jPlayer.pause(); // this will turn off every music player
        });
   });
</script>
```

This would stop the music inside both the blue container and red container.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted what `stop` is.

Regardless, mouseleave takes a function:

```
$('#container').mouseleave(function() {
    alert();
}
```

or

```
$('#container').on('mouseleave', function() {
    alert();
}
```

If the DOM could change, use:

```
$(document).on('mouseleave', '#container', function() {
    alert();
}
```

I can't find `#container` in your HTML. If there's multiple containers you should change the id to a class.